# Const char* weird behavior

Tags: c++, static, undefined-behavior, behavior

Hello im having problems with const char* being the same in a weird way.
Color::Text() returns a static char array but it is also used to initialize const char* pointer for array.

wtf do i do if i want rofl::Default to actually work and not be the latest "const char" it Color::Text produced?

```
#include <windows.h>
class Color
{
public:
    int R;
    int G;
    int B;
    int A;
    Color(int r, int b, int g, int a = 255)
    {
    R = r;
    G = g;
    B = b;
    A = a;
    }
    const char* Text()
    {
    static char Texts[124];
    snprintf(Texts, 124, "%i %i %i %i", R, G, B, A);
    return Texts;
    }
}
class rofl
{
public:
    const char* Default;
    const char* Value;
    rofl(const char* d)
    {
        Default = d;
        Value = d;
    }
}

rofl dood("0");
rofl doaaod(Color(0,0,0).Text());
rofl xxxx(Color(0,55,0).Text());

int main()
{
    printf("%s %s\n", dood.Default, dood.Value);
    printf("%s %s\n", doaaod.Default, doaaod.Value);
    printf("%s %s\n", xxxx.Default, xxxx.Value);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
0 0
0 55 0 0 0 0
0 55 0 0 55 0
```

Comment: In the constructor of `rofl` create a buffer (e.g. using operator `new`) for `Default` and `Value` to point at.  Then copy data to those buffers.   Better yet, use `std::string` objects instead of `char *`,  and the dynamic allocation will be managed cleanly for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one character buffer in your code (apart from the literal strings). A `const char*` is a pointer to a character buffer, not a new buffer that is a copy of the original.

So, it is natural that each time you call Color::Text you are writing over the same character buffer and all pointers to it will read the same.

You must understand the notion of pointers in C and C++.

In this case, in C++ and for the behaviour that you need, you should replace all uses of `const char*` by `std::string`.

I recommend you the book "Accelerated C++" to learn C++ easily without going into the details that are a bit archaic in the language.

Comment: i cant use trash like std::string

Comment: @Lolmelon: Your question is tagged [tag:c++]. If you cannot use C++, don't tag it as such.

Comment: @Lolmelon: "Trash"?

Comment: @Lolmelon, `std::string` is not trash. You decide if you want to learn modern C++ or 1970s-style programming. In that case, go read "The C Programming Language", you will understand the problem with your code fully in the end.